# System Does Not Boot From Various Bootable Recovery Disks

Tags: bios, system-restore, disk-utility

No matter what recovery system I have used, be it Acronis recovery disk or some other recovery disk that is intended for emergency system restoration, my system just stalls but still responds seemingly awaiting response while underscore is blinking. Sometimes power button does function, but sometimes does not and I have to hold it down for a few seconds for system to turn off.

Let's look at yesterday's case with Paragon Backup & Recovery software which I use to backup my OS and that allows creation of bootable recovery disk. On the image below you will see this very recovery disk stalls on main screen if choosing "Normal Mode" but proceeds with "Safe-Mode" option. The blue bar appears below and immediately stalls. Recovery program becomes unresponsive and flashdrive's LED ceases to blink:

[image]

After proceeding with "Safe-Mode" option, a command-line screen appears with recovery program executing commands but soon stalls. The underscore is blinking and system shutdown is possible (which is not the case with main screen):

[image]

I feel the need to emphasize that the problems outlined here are not observed on my other 2 and 6 year old laptops with this recovery program and others. I am positive that it is not matter of media being used here and assuming the problem or misconfiguration in system BIOS.

*Dell Latitude E6420*
*Windows 7 Enterprise*

Comment: So clear the BIOS settings and set them again. But most likely, this is a hardware problem, not a BIOS settings problem.

Comment: Do you think it is somehow connected with this? http://superuser.com/questions/471008/fastgate-a20-line-and-himem-sys-issue-with-updating-bios

Comment: I would contact Dell Support about this.