# Why I Get BSOD When Running From Cloned HDD Before Windows 7 Startup?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bsod, disk-cloning

So I have cloned with XXClone my Intel 330i 120GB SSD to my older WD 250GB HDD which I decided to make fallback external drive and placed in 2.5" HDD USB 2.0 enclosure case:

[image: HDD 2.5" Enclosure Case]

[image: Options]

After choosing first option which was the only option available, the process completed successfully but after disabling main SSD and making cloned HDD main boot device and trying to boot into Windows from it, I've got BSOD and immediately system restarted. Not sure what could have gone wrong but prior to cloning I wanted to clone through DriveImage XML which clones using either Volume Locking and Volume Shadow Services and both failed because I was receiving error about failure to lock volume. Maybe such cloning requires these techniques to clone properly... Tried Unlocker to unlock and kill processes using volume to no avail in the end. I know there is CloneZilla but I wanted to stay farther from risk being affraid I won't boot from main SSD for some reason.

Comment: Are you trying to boot FROM the external drive?

Comment: Yes from external drive.

Comment: The reason you are getting this behavior is becase your trying to boot from an external device.

Comment: What makes external drive with same data different than internal drive?

Comment: **I am not Microsoft.**  I just know its a problem.

Comment: Maybe USB interface causes error. I will see if I can clone with CloneZilla.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to clone a currently running Windows. You won't be able to copy many files, and some that can copy will be in inconsistent state. Instead consider booting with something like Hiren's BootCD or CloneZilla Live or any other bootable system and do disk cloning from there. That way you'll ensure that all of your files are not in use and properly closed.

If you do it that way, your system will boot.

Comment: Unfortunately my laptop cannot boot linux type or MS-DOS type bootable rescue utilities: http://superuser.com/questions/513600/system-does-not-boot-from-various-bootable-recovery-disks