# HP laptop stuck in boot loop, UBCD stops at black screen with text and blinking cursor

Tags: windows, windows-vista

i'm trying to fix a laptop for a friend who has no explanation as to why it stopped working.

When I turn it on it starts to boot, but gets to Windows splash screen and restarts. Does the same thing again and again.

I tried a Windows password reset disk, which loads and works fine, but still stuck in boot loop. I tried to boot with the UBCD which starts to load, but stops on black screen with text at top of screen

> ISOLINUX 4.04 2011-04-18 ETCD Copyright (c) 1994-2011 H. peter anvin et al

and a blinking cursor under that. I know the disk is good.

Comment: are you asking for help fixing the computer or why the disk doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Windows **Safe-Mode** or **Step-By-Step Confirmation** to customize boot? Another thing is I have similar thing when trying to boot with any *"Recovery Disk"* out there, including basic [Kaspersky Rescue Disk 10](http://support.kaspersky.com/4162). Everytime I see cursor blinking in the end and I think (in my case at least) it has to do with BIOS settings in particular with A20 line, the [actual issue I have question for](https://superuser.com/questions/471008/fastgate-a20-line-and-himem-sys-issue-with-updating-bios). I heard it must be turned off as it being hindrance for loading drivers/devices in *High Memory Area* (HMA) under DOS mode. I have tried even so to say safe-mode which is also present in some boot recovery programs, like *Paragon Backup & Recovery* which did not work as well.

I think to confirm if my second point relevant to your friend's laptop, you should try burning Kaspersky Rescue Disk on mere CD or CD-RW and trying loading it to see if it boots so you know it something that is not connected with Windows continuous boot. If it proves to be the case, you now at least will know that there are 2 separate issues with your friend's laptop so you won't end up chasing your own tail if you know what I mean.